# Given the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is $\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\}$ reflexive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I don't know if it's reflexive because of the missing pair $(4,4). $

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That is enough to make $\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\}$ a non-reflexive relation over $\{1,2,3,4\}$, yes.

A reflexive relation $R$ (over a set $A$) must have $(a,a) \in R$ for each and every single $a \in A$. You've found a case where that does not hold.

Comment: Okay, thank you. So this is not reflexive, but can it be transitive?

Comment: If you have other questions, it would be best to make a new question post, and include your thoughts/workings on the matter, as opposed to asking a sequence of questions on an existing post